# Addition not working in c

Tags: c, printf, addition, format-specifiers

I was trying c code to add but my program doesn't execute, codeblocks unfortunately closes. What is the error?

```
void main()
{
    float  a,b;

    printf("%30sAddition Of Numbers\n");
    printf("\nEnter Number 1: ");
    scanf("%f",&a);
    printf("\nEnter Number 2: ");
    scanf("%f",&b);

    printf("\nThe addition of %0.3f and %0.3f is %0.3f",a,b,(a+b));

}
```

I want to put the result of addition directly in printf statement with float inputs but I am not getting it working.

I also tried putting the result in variable a but it didn't work either.

```
    void main()
{
    float  a,b;

    printf("%30sAddition Of Numbers\n");
    printf("\nEnter Number 1: ");
    scanf("%f",&a);
    printf("\nEnter Number 2: ");
    scanf("%f",&b);
    a=a+b;
    printf("\nThe addition of %0.3f and %0.3f is %0.3f",a,b,a);

}
```

where am I going wrong?

Comment: what's the error your getting?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: codeblocks doesnt execute. windows error is displayed.. codeblocks unfortunately stopped working

Comment: The only issue I see directly is that you are not including the header files... but it could be you just excluded it from your example?

Comment: I have included the header files in my program

Comment: I just realized now that codeblocks is a compiler.  Unfortunately I'm unfamiliar with it - though I believe that this should compile and run just fine in a standard C compiler such as GCC - aside from the issue with the second test - noted by @pFFed

Comment: @BrianRiley Codeblocks is *not* a compiler, it's an IDE.  On Windows it's usually used with mingw (so gcc, more or less).  Sometimes beginners miss the distinction between their IDE and the tools behind it, though.

Comment: You should not use void main, but either int main(void) or int main()

Comment: @Dmitri - Thanks for clearing that up for me :)  I had never heard of Codeblocks - my epiphany was that he was talking about software.  Without doing more research I should have left it at that rather than saying compiler ;-)

Comment: @pratikwatwani - _[Here is a good explanation of how to format output](https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_31.htm)_, including leading spaces before your numeric output.

Comment: a=a+b;
    printf("\nThe addition of %0.3f and %0.3f is %0.3f",a,b,a);
You need another variable c so that   c=a+b;
    printf("\nThe addition of %0.3f and %0.3f is %0.3f",a,b,c);

Comment: *Code::Blocks* stops working and closes? Not your program? That shouldn't happen even if your program crashes.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in the following statement

```
 printf("%30sAddition Of Numbers\n");
```

here, the format string supplied to the `printf()` conatins `%30s` (or, `%s`, in general) which is a format specifier (conversion specifier), and you did not supply any argument to it. It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To quote `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.1

> [...] If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
>   undefined. [...]

You can also check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) to find out more about the format specifiers.

---

EDIT:

As discussed in the below comments, if you want some spaces to appear before the output, change

```
printf("\t\tAddition Of Numbers\n");
```

That said,

- `void main()` should be `int main (void)`, at least, to conform to the standards.
- You should always check the return value of `scanf()` to ensure the successful scanning.

Comment: But i thought that it is used to give a space.

Comment: what does it mean then? the program works with %30s when i use all integer numbers and not float! how do i make it work with floats.

Comment: @pratikwatwani well, read the linked article for undefined behavior. :)

Comment: @pratikwatwani You're welcome. You can also [consider accepting an answer that helped you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062).

Answer (score 1):

The *"%30sAddition Of Numbers\n"* issue in your post has been addressed by two good answers (at the time of this post).  But you asked a question in comments that may not have been answered completely:

*works with %30s when i use all integer numbers and not float! how do i make it work with floats.*

A generic answer to that question:
The format specifier you use in *scanf()*: `"%f",&a` could result in undesirable results if scanning in unexpected newlines, spaces or other white space. This can be addressed  by modifying the format specifier string to suppress these characters.  Here is a suggestion:

```
char* fmt = "%[^\n]%*c";//This generic format specifier, can be used for both integer
                        //and floating point inputs when used in conjuction
                        //with strtod() or strtol() (see below)
scanf(fmt, input);
```

Explanation of *["%[^\n]%*c"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30070821/645128)*.

When a user is asked to enter a generic *number*, it might be a float or an integer.  You can accommodate that by creating methods for both, and being specific about what kind of value you would like to process:

```
float get_float(void)
{
    char input[80];
    char **dummy={0};
    char* fmt = "%[^\n]%*c";
    printf("Enter floating point number and hit return:\n");
    scanf(fmt, input);
    return strtod(input, dummy);
}

long get_int(void)
{
    char input[80];
    char **dummy={0};
    char* fmt = "%[^\n]%*c";
    printf("Enter integer number and hit return:\n");
    scanf(fmt, input);
    return strtol(input, dummy, 10);
}
```

Called like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    long integer_var = get_int();
    float float_var = get_float();
    float sum = (float)integer_var + float_var;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Try adding getch(); function at the bottom before closing curly brackets,

like this

```
void main()
 {
  
  float  a,b;
  printf("%30sAddition Of Numbers\n");
  printf("\nEnter Number 1: ");
  scanf("%f",&a);
  printf("\nEnter Number 2: ");
  scanf("%f",&b);
  a=a+b;
  printf("\nThe addition of %0.3f and %0.3f is %0.3f",a,b,a);
  getch();//it will hold your output screen so you can see the output 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
printf("%30sAddition Of Numbers\n");
```

you did not supply a string argument for the `%s` format. This causes *undefined behaviour*.

If you want the output spaced, you could try a small modification

```
printf("%30s\n", "Addition Of Numbers");
```

in this case you are supplying a *string literal* to satisfy the `%s` format.

Additionally you must *always* check the return value from `scanf` to see that it did convert the number of arguments it was supposed to. It's a basic newbie error not to, and the root cause of hundreds of SO questions.

Comment: okay.that worked but when i change all floats to integer that works. how? what do i do next?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, please be more specific, or ask another question if it's a new problem!

Comment: the %s format works when i change all my data types to integer values, but it doesnt work in the above case, why?

Comment: Because not supplying an argument for `%s` is ***undefined behaviour***. What happens next for "when this" or "when that" is irrelevant.