# How to scanning this line with fscanf?

Tags: scanf

Given file with the only line:

> 001**005**02**3000.00**28

How can I scan this file (file.txt) and create structure like this:

```
a=001  b=005  c=02  d=3000.00  e=28
```

I want to do it with fscanf, but my problem it's that in this line don't exist spaces, and thus, I don't know what is the format that I need to write in `fscanf(..)`

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30070821/6910411) and still I don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did I understand correctly, you are reading in a fixed-field line?

You could try

```
unsigned int a, b, c, e;
float d;    
fscanf(file, "%3u%3u%2u%7f%2u", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);
printf("a=%u b=%u c=%u d=%f e=%u", a, b, c, d, e);
```