# What does scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &s); actually do?

Tags: c, scanf

I know for a fact that [^\n] is a delimiter that makes scanf to scan everything until "enter" key is hit. But I don't know what the remainder of **"%[^\n]%*c"** is used for. Also why do we have to mention "&s" instead of "s" in the scanf function.

I tried running this:

```
char s[100];
scanf("%[^\n]s",s);      
scanf("%[^\n]s",&s);
```

**Both** the above **scanf statements worked exactly the same for me**. If there is any difference between them, What is it?

Also **Why should I prefer** scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &s); **to the above declarations?**

Comment: For an array that has decayed to a pointer, as in your scanf call, `s`, `&s`, and `&s[0]` all refer to the same address. Where did you hear you should prefer `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &s);`?

Comment: Quite similar, Possible duplicate of [What does \`scanf("%\*\[^\n\]%\*c")\` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065675/what-does-scanf-nc-mean)

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &s);` is akin to `gets()`.  Use neither.  Instead use `fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin)`.

Comment: You should prefer `fgets()`, but if you must `%[^\n]` is a `[...]` (character class) format specifier matching all characters that are `'^'` ('not' when included 1st) a newline. (which allows reading whitespace). The `'*'` character is the *assignment suppression* modifier that allows reading/discarding the type for that *conversion specifier* (a single char here, e.g. the `'\n'`). When `'*'` is used, any conversion is not added to the *match count* (e.g. the return).

Comment: This declaration was originally used in Hackerrank. Why to go for fgets instead of scanf("%[^\n]s",s) ?

Comment: Because what remains in your input buffer after the call does not depend on the conversion specifier used (or any reading/discarding of additional characters). Just use `fgets` and trim the newline by overwriting the the *nul-terminating* character -- it will save many headaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scanf("%[^\n]s",&s);` has *many* troubles:

> No check of return value.
>   No overrun protection
>   No consumption of `'\n'`
>   No assignment of `s` on `'\n'` only
>   No need for `s` in `"%[^\n]s"`
>   Wrong type `&s` with format.

`scanf("%[^\n]s",s);` only has one less problem (last one).

Use `fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin)`

```
if (fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin)) {
  s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = 0; // Lop off potential ending \n
  // Success
} else {
  // failure
}
```

---

- No check of return value.

Without checking the return value, success of reading is unknown and the state of `s` indeterminate.

- No overrun protection

What happens when the 100th character is inputted? - "Very bad. Not good. Not good." [Necron 99, Wizards 1977](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=wizards)

- No consumption of `'\n'`

`'\n'`  remains in `stdin` to foul up the next read.

- No assignment of `s` on `'\n'` only

If the input begin with `'\n'`, scanf() returns and `s` unchanged.  It is not assigned `""`.

- No need for `"s"` in `"%[^\n]s"`

The `"s"` is not part of the specifier `"%[^\n]"`.  Drop it.

- Wrong type `&s` with format.

`%[...]` matches a `char *`, not a pointer to a `char[100]` like `&s`  (UB).

Comment: Sound advice. Of course SO would lose 30% of questions were it not for the pitfalls surrounding the misuse of `scanf` `:)`

Comment: I am a newbie here. Thanks for the swift and elaborate answer but it would help me much more if you could explain more on your listed bullet points as I still can't get the grasp of it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Today `scanf()`, [tomorrow the world!!!!](http://littlefun.org/posts/Today_you_tomorrow_the_world)

Comment: I want your picture collection `:)`

Comment: @Alagusankar - take bullet 1 -- how to fix? (check the return). Bullet 2 - use the *field-width modifier* see [scanf(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html), Bullet 3 - you request a match of a literal `'s'` following a collection of characters not a `'\n'`, Bullet 4 follows from 3, Bullet 5 - explains `%[...]` is a complete *conversion specifier* in its own right, the `'s'` that follows must match a literal `'s'` in the input (your use is superfluous)., Bullet 6 follows from 5. (or make life easy, use `fgets()`)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a string as input in C using scanf(“%s”, s). But, it accepts string only until it finds the first space.

In order to take a line as input, you can use scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s); where s is defined as char s[MAX_LEN] where MAX_LEN is the maximum size of s . Here, [] is the scanset character. ^\n stands for taking input until a newline isn't encountered. Then, with this %*c, it reads the newline character and here, the used * indicates that this newline character is discarded.

Note: After inputting the character and the string, inputting the sentence by the above mentioned statement won't work. This is because, at the end of each line, a new line character (\n) is present. So, the statement: scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s); will not work because the last statement will read a newline character from the previous line. This can be handled in a variety of ways and one of them being: scanf("\n"); before the last statement.