# meaning of this scanf { scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s);} in c

Tags: c, string, scanf

```
int main()

{

char s[100];

char s1[] ={"Hello, World!"};

scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s); // The statement that we are interested in//

printf("%s",s1);

printf("\n");

printf("%s",s);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Perhaps [a decent `scanf` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) might be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

There are already some post about this argument, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065675/what-does-scanf-nc-mean). By the way:
with `%[^\n]` you are taking input until a newline isn't encountered. With `%*c` you take the newline character and then discard it (this is useful when you are using fgets after scanf).