# About entering a value with spaces for "scanf()"

Tags: c, scanf

I need help with my project homework
The problem is, how can I enter a value with spaces using scanf() and gets()?

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct person {

    char *name_lastname[30];
    char *job[30];

};

int main()
{
int number;
printf("How many names will you enter? ");
scanf("%d", &number);

    struct person *people = (struct person*) malloc(number*sizeof(struct person));
    
    for(int i = 0; i<number; i++)
    {
        printf("name and last name: ");
        gets((people+i)->name_lastname);
    
        printf("job: ");
        gets((people+i)->job);
    }
    
    
    return 0;

}
```

I know there are similar answers here for this.

> [How do you allow spaces to be entered using scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf) "But we are not allowed to use `fgets()` in our assignment."

Or such uses solve my problem, I tried all of them.
`scanf("%10[0-9a-zA-Z ]", &number);`
`scanf("%19[^\n]", &number);`

As you can see, the functions I can use are very limited as it is a project assignment.
`strlen()`, `fgets()` I am not allowed to use such functions.

My algorithm malfunctions when I enter a blank value without using scanf() and gets() .

Comment: There are 7,224 questions tagged ```scanf```. One would think that to be abundant. I do not know what your teacher is trying to accomplish with this. ```gets``` is a dangerous function and shouldn't be used. It was already outdated in the 90's, and removed from the language in ```C11```. It is no longer a part of ```C```. ```scanf``` is no better than ```gets``` when reading an array of characters without a specified limit. But as you're limited to these two, read ```scanf```'s man page, you'd find all the information you need there. You should also be checking the return value of ```scanf```.

Comment: If your instructor is requiring you to use `gets()` instead of `fgets()`, then you should quit that class.

Comment: @Haris Thanks for my comment my friend, believe me, I have looked at many topics, but I will continue to look. This is my university teacher, I can't leave the class in my head.

Comment: Baran Kanat, `gets()` is no longer part of the C standard library since C11 (11+ years ago).  Better to learn modern C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research, I solved the problem. Perhaps the compiler thinks that we have entered the value in another element for scanf() when we enter a blank value, or I understood it that way.

The resources below helped me a lot.

> [`scanf(“%[^\n]s”, str)` Vs `gets(str)` in C with Examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanfns-str-vs-getsstr-in-c-with-examples/)

> [What does `scanf("%*[^\n]%*c")` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065675/what-does-scanf-nc-mean)

Algorithm working properly:

```
struct person {

    char name_lastname[30];
    char job[30];

};

int main()
{
int number;
printf("How many names will you enter? ");
scanf("%d", &number);

    struct person *people = (struct person*) malloc(number*sizeof(struct person));

    for(int i = 0; i<number; i++)
    {
        printf("name and last name: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", (people+i)->name_lastname);

        printf("job: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", (people+i)->name_lastname);
    }


    return 0;

}
```

Places I changed in my code: `gets((people+i)->name_lastname);` ==> `scanf(" %[^\n]", (people+i)->name_lastname);`

`gets((people+i)->job);` ==> `scanf(" %[^\n]", (people+i)->job);`

Comment: `scanf(" %[^\n]", (people+i)->name_lastname);` without a _width_ is bad practice.   Better as `scanf(" %29[^\n]", (people+i)->name_lastname);`. Certainly your 2nd call `scanf(" %[^\n]", (people+i)->name_lastname);` is amiss to save the job in the name.

Comment: Cast not needed.  Better to allocate to the referenced object than type. `people = (struct person*) malloc(number*sizeof(struct person));` --> `people = malloc(sizeof people[0] * number);`

Comment: Thanks for the warnings, I saw that the algorithm worked more efficiently after applying what you said. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

```
typedef struct person {
char name_lastname[30];
char job[30];
} person;
char c;
...
fprintf(stdout,"print name and last_name:\n");
fscanf(stdout,"%s%[\n]%c",people[i].name_lastname,&c);
fprintf(stdout,"print occupation:\n");
fscanf(stdout,"%s%[\n]%c",people[i].job,&c);
....
```

Comment: Sorry mate, using scanf() function is forbidden for me.

Comment: @BaranKanat  "using scanf() function is forbidden for me" is in conflict with "how can I enter a value with spaces using scanf() and gets()?".  Please resolve.

Comment: Peter Irich, Review `fscanf(stdout,"%s%[\n]%c", people[i].name_lastname, &c);`.  How do you expect to read from `stdout`?

Comment: I'm sorry, of course about "fscanf(stdout,..)" is error.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica sorry i can use `scanf()` but using `fscanf()` is forbidden for me.

Comment: @BaranKanat Any answer that uses `fscanf(stdin,...` can be replaced with `scanf()`.  This answer certainty should be using ``fscanf(stdin,...` and not ``fscanf(stdout,...`.  Aside form that, "but using fscanf() is forbidden" should be a trivial edit for you to perform.